# Scraping the data based on automatically access the multiple pages based on href

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am having the problem of automating the multiple pages using the selenium webdriver and python. In my code, I am getting the pages clicked automatically upto 10 pages but after the 10 pages, it won't work. I am not getting the page clicking after page number 11.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pandas as pd
import os



url = 'http://www.igrmaharashtra.gov.in/eASR/eASRCommon.aspx? 
hDistName=Buldhana'
chrome_path = r'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/chromedriver.exe'
d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
d.implicitly_wait(10)
d.get(url)



Select(d.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$ddlTaluka')).select_by_value('7')
Select(d.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$ddlVillage')).select_by_value('1464') 
 page = [page.get_attribute('href')for page in 
 d.find_elements_by_css_selector( 
 "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate [href*='Page$']")]

while True:
         pages = [page.get_attribute('href')for page in 
         d.find_elements_by_css_selector( 
         "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate 
         [href*='Page$']")]



         for script_page in pages:
            d.execute_script(script_page)
            #print(script_page)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using page indexes and check whether the page is available and you have to click on each page and go on.Try the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.igrmaharashtra.gov.in/eASR/eASRCommon.aspx?hDistName=Buldhana'
chrome_path = r'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/chromedriver.exe'
d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
d.implicitly_wait(10)
d.get(url)
Select(d.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$ddlTaluka')).select_by_value('7')
Select(d.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$ddlVillage')).select_by_value('1464')
i=2
while True:
    if len(d.find_elements_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate a[href*='Page${}']".format(i)))>0:
        print( d.find_elements_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate a[href*='Page${}']".format(i))[0].get_attribute('href'))
        d.find_elements_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate a[href*='Page${}']".format(i))[0].click()
        i+=1
    else:
        break
```

Output:
Since i started from page 2.

---

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$2')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$3')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$4')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$5')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$6')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$7')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$8')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$9')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$10')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$11')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$12')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$13')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$14')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$15')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$16')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$17')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$18')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$19')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$20')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$21')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$22')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$23')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$24')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$25')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$26')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$27')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$28')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$29')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$30')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$31')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$32')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$33')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$34')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$35')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$36')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$37')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$38')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$39')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$40')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$41')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate','Page$42')

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: In this if i want the data to be concatenate starting from page 1 to page 42. It is unable to save the table data after page 10

Comment: That should be a separate question and please post a new question and mentioned your expected output.Thanks.

Comment: I have posted the new question with some modification in the coding. Link is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472156/having-error-in-the-concatenation-of-the-data-for-the-multiple-pages-in-python

Comment: Please assist for that link question.

Comment: @ParulDeshmukh : Ok.I'll check that later.

Comment: Have you found some solution for the above mention link.

Comment: Can you please suggest on the question posted 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58112213/how-to-read-the-sublist-from-the-main-list-and-add-the-sublist-in-the-another-da