# Having error in the concatenation of the data for the multiple pages in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am facing the error while concatenating the data of the multiple pages and exporting it in the single CSV file. According to my code, the data is exporting upto page 10 but after page number 10 it is working.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pandas as pd
import os

url = 'http://www.igrmaharashtra.gov.in/eASR/eASRCommon.aspx? 
hDistName=Buldhana'
chrome_path =
```

r'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/chromedriver.exe'

```
d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
d.implicitly_wait(10)
d.get(url)
```

Select(d.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$ddlTaluka')).select_by_value('7')
Select(d.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$ddlVillage')).select_by_value('1464')

```
tableElement = d.find_element_by_id(
    'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate')
table = pd.read_html(tableElement.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
#print(table)
table.columns = table.iloc[0]
table = table.iloc[1:]
#print(type(table))
table = table[table.Select == 'SurveyNo']
#print(table) #assumption SurveyNo exists for all wanted rows
surveyNo_scripts = [item.get_attribute('href') for item in
```

d.find_elements_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWi 
    seRate [href*='Select$']")]

```
#print(surveyNo_scripts)
i = 0
for script in surveyNo_scripts:
    d.execute_script(script)
    surveys = d.find_element_by_css_selector('textarea').text
    table.iloc[[i],table.columns.get_loc('Select')] = surveys
    i += 1

print(table)

j=2
while True:
if len(d.find_elements_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate a[href*='Page${}']".format(j)))>0:

 #print( d.find_elements_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate a[href*='Page${}']".format(i))[0].get_attribute('href'))
    d.find_elements_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate a[href*='Page${}']".format(j))[0].click()
    tableElement = d.find_element_by_css_selector( 
    "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate")
    table1 = pd.read_html(tableElement.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
    table1.columns = table1.iloc[0]
    table1 = table1.iloc[1:]
    #print(type(table))
    table1 = table1[table1.Select == 'SurveyNo']
    #print(table) #assumption SurveyNo exists for all wanted rows
    surveyNo_scripts = [item.get_attribute('href') for item in 
    d.find_elements_by_css_selector(
                "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate 
    [href*='Select$']")]
    #print(surveyNo_scripts)
    i = 0
    for script in surveyNo_scripts:
                    d.execute_script(script)
                    surveys = 
                    d.find_element_by_css_selector('textarea').text
                    table1.iloc[[i],table1.columns.get_loc('Select')] = 
                    surveys
                    i += 1

    #print(table1)
    #table = table.append(table1.reindex(columns=table.columns))
    table1.columns = table.columns
    table = pd.concat([table, table1] ,ignore_index=True)
    print(table)
    j+=1
else:
    break
table.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\Sample_buldhana.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```